# iPhone 4 jailbreak gone wrong

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

My phone is currently glitched and I am unable to access the stock apps, but I'm able to use downloaded apps by searching them and tapping on them.
I cant download or delete apps. What should I do? Should I just full restore?

Answer (score 2):

Run `uicache` as mobile, then respring.